# Python selenium - "No modal dialog is currently open exception in selenium"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am getting input url's and trying to load it in the browser (Firefox - Updated version). The script has been working for all the url's. Except few URLs return this error

> "No modal dialog is currently open"

I tried adding `driver.switch_to_alert().accept()` but no help. I usually end up closing browser and restart it all over again.

Please find the code :

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
capabilities['marionette'] = True
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
print ("Number of rows to be processed is:" + str(ws1.max_row))
for row in range(2,ws1.max_row+1):
    try:
        region = ws1["E"+str(row)].value
        # Reading Row 'row'
        print("Reading row #"+str(row))
        url = ws1["C"+str(row)].value
        regex = df[df['Country'] == region]['Regex'].values[0]
        #Load mainpage or input URL
        i = 0
        while i < 3:
            try:
                driver.get("http://"+url)
                driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
                time.sleep(5)
                break
            except (TimeoutException,WebDriverException,NoSuchElementException) as e:
                print(e,'Retrying...',i+1)
            i += 1
```

Sample URLs :

```
afilias.info
www.nuwavenow.com
www.IntoTomorrow.com
www.picobrew.com
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is leading to this error and some URLs that work, and some URLs that don't.

Comment: I do not see any alert popup in first 2 websites

Comment: Even I don't see any. But i get "no modal dialog is currently open" exception for second url.

Comment: @AswathaRavi Looks like the error message is from `switch_to_alert()`. Then this would be the cause of the problem. Could you add the full stack trace in order to know exactly where the error is raised.